# HTTPS Socket.io connection with sails backend

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I'm receiving the following error when connecting the socket through my react app:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://staging.app.com/#/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://staging.app.com/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LxY7amx'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I tried the following solution but none seems to work:

```
io('https://staging.app.com', {  secure: true })

io('staging.app.com');

io('staging.app.com', {  secure: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client), you can set a url using the following method.

```
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  io.sails.url = 'https://staging.app.com';
</script>
```

Comment: That do not seems to be working, still it is taking http